# Adding a custom vbo action in drupal 6

Tags: 6, views, actions

```
function custom_profile_action_info() {
  return array(
    'custom_profile_mail_action' => array(
     'type' => 'system',
     'description' => t('Custom Send Mail'),
     'configurable' => TRUE,
     'permissions' => array('access content'),
     'pass rows' => TRUE,
    ),
  );
}




    function custom_profile_mail_action($object,$context) {
      global $user;
   drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params = array(), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE) 
$check =drupal_mail('custom_profile',custom_profile_send_mail','abc@redcom.in', language_default(), array(),NULL, TRUE);
         drupal_set_message('enters the action');


    }
```

For adding a custom action I have written the above code but I dont get it listed in views bulk operations list in new view of format vbo
What can be the issue?

Comment: Try adding `'hooks' => array('any' => TRUE)` to the action definition

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/459070 I got my answer in this link . Thanks @Clive